# How to configure React Native Image picker styling?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

When i'm getting an image from the gallery in react-native-image-picker, i need to:

--change the font and colour of the Cancel, Play and Choose buttons

--change color of the progress bar from blue color

--remove the 'compressing video' text here

--change the background color behind the video from the deep black
[image]

Comment: Check if what you want exist here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md if not that's mean you should play with the lib source code

Comment: The Reference doc you linked is more for the usage. I don't know where in the lib source code to make the changes to achieve the look i want